# Using $anchorScroll on ng-repeat tr elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, anchor-scroll

I'm having difficulty getting an $anchorScroll to function so that clicking a tr element scrolls the screen so that the tr is at the very top of the screen

I have a repeater, with tr elements that look like

```
<tr ng-click='selectRow(row, $index);' id="trRow{{row.RowId}}">
```

My select order method looks like

```
    $scope.selectRow = function (row, index) {

        $location.hash('#trRow' + row.RowId);
        $anchorScroll();
        ....
```

I inject both $location and $anchorScroll into my controller, and if I console.log either, I can see that they contain the correct data. I can also verify that row is correctly passed to the method.

With the above code, no scrolling events occur.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for a very late answer, but I had the same problem and wound up here. Couldn't really get why it didn't work, but the way I solved it was by placing an empty span with the id the first td, then just the rest as you did it.